# Are the Hermite polynomials a complete orthonormal set? A question concerning the book on Malliavin calculus from Nualart

Tags: stochastic-analysis, malliavin-calculus

In the pages 6 - 7 of the book ["The Malliavin Calculus and Related Topics"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F3-540-28329-3) from Nualart one reads:

[image]

[image]

Theorem 1.1.1 states the following:

[image]

So, it is clear that $H_n(W_1(x)) = H_n(x)$ is a complete orthogonal system.

However, how do we see that the norm of $H_n(x)$ is 1?

When we look back on the book, we find

[image]

So it seems that $\Bbb{E}_\nu[H_n(x) H_n(x)] = \frac{1}{n!}$

In this casem this would be a typo on the book.

Is this the case? or am I missing something?

Edit: The proof seems to work if $Y = X$

[image]

Also we might wonder that the result does not follow because $(X,X)$ might not be Gaussian, so it might be good to ask what do we mean by a Gaussian vector: I take the definition from Le Gall (Mouvement Brownian, martingales  et calcul stochastique --page 3):

[image]

Comment: You can't apply that for $X=Y,$ because $(X,X)$ does not have a Gaussian distribution, being concentrated on a line. The "probabilists' Hermite polynomials" are known to be orthonormal (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials), in other contexts, they may be written $He_n(x)$.

Comment: I think you are right , but still I don't understand exactly what you say @ProfessorVector: To have a gaussian distribution we only need that linear combinations of $(X_1,\ldots ,X_n)$ have gaussian distribution right? That is the case for $(X,X)$ furthermore, the proof of this relationship works fine if you use Y = X, see the edit.  I edited the question so that thre argument becomes more transparent and you can point out more easily my mistake

Comment: @ProfessorVector, I have looked at Wikipedia article and couldn't find the norm one property of the probabilist Hermite  polynomial (with respect to the measure $\nu$), could you point it out for me?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misinterpreted the sentence "An equivalent formulation of the fact that Hermite polynomials are an orthogonal basis for $L^2(\Bbb{R}, w(x) dx)$ consists in introducing Hermite functions (see below), and in saying that the Hermite functions are an orthonormal basis for $L^2(\Bbb{R})$", meaning something completely different. In fact, there's a formula $\int^\infty_{-\infty}He_m(x)\, He_n(x)\,e^{-\frac{x^2}2 }\,dx=\sqrt{2\pi}\,n!\,\delta_{nm}$ showing that the $H_n$ from your book are _not_ the $He_n$ at Wikipedia. I have to admit that my objection against $X=Y$ was not justified.